# I try to replace the backward slash with forward slash using gsub but it's not working

Tags: ruby, string

```
puts "C:\WATIR\gopal\**".gsub("\\", "/")
```

It's giving me the output

```
C:WATIRgopal**
```

Can anyone suggest me where do I go wrong?

Comment: There are no backslashes in your string.

Comment: Yes, that was acting as a escape character now, it's clear.

Comment: And you seem to know that already, because you correctly escaped your backslashes in the first argument to `gsub` ;-)

Comment: No, I have mistaken that as a backslash, that's why the problem.

Comment: Then your reasoning is self-inconsistent: if you thought that a single backslash would mean a backslash, then your `gsub` would not replace backslashes with forward slashes, it would only replace *pairs of two backslashes in a row* with forward slashes.

Comment: I haven't thought of backslashes as escape character while I write that code though I know that. So I have mistaken it. But now it's clear. But I don't use to escape the backslashes rather I would use single codes. Because my requirement to replace the backslashes with forward slashes.

Comment: But you *did* treat the backslash as an escape character in the first argument to `gsub`, where you *correctly* escaped it. And somehow you thought that the backslash would only need escaping in one string but not in the other string. You need to figure out why you thought that and whether there is some deeper misunderstanding at work, otherwise you will run into the same problem again. That's what I am trying to get at.

Comment: Okay, I got you, thanks.

Comment: Jörg W Mittag I don't understand `C:\WATIR\gopal\**` here it's treated as the character as it is. but when I write inside tr('\\','/'), I still write inside '  ' but why do I have to escape that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the `#gsub`, but with the string construction itself:

```
"C:\WATIR\gopal\**" # => "C:WATIRgopal**"
```

---

`\` is used for escaping character. `\W` for example will try go escape the `W` character, instead of make two characters - `\` and `W`. One way to fix it is to escape the escaping with another `\`:

```
"C:\\WATIR\\gopal\\**" # => "C:\\WATIR\\gopal\\**"
```

The better way is to use single quotes, where `\` has no special meaning:

```
'C:\WATIR\gopal\**' # => "C:\\WATIR\\gopal\\**"
```

---

Additionally, prefer `#tr` over `#gsub` when you want to replace a single character with another:

```
'C:\WATIR\gopal\**'.tr('\\', '/') # => "C:/WATIR/gopal/**"
```

Comment: I don't understand `'C:\WATIR\gopal\**'` here it's treated as the character as it is. but when I write inside tr('\\','/'), I still write inside ' ' but why do I have to escape that?

Comment: @Gopal, ok, what I said was almost accurate. Backslash inside single quotes doesn't have the meaning of escaping characters, except for the character `'`. So if you want to write a string with the single `'` character inside, using single quotes, you have to use `'\''`. In `'\'`, ruby sees that the next character is `'` and uses the backslash to escape it, as opposed to use it literally and close the string with the `'`.

Answer (score 1):

In your question,.

**`puts "C:\WATIR\gopal\**".gsub("\\", "/")`**
 gives

**`C:WATIRgopal**`**

because it is treating `\` as an escape character and leaving it.

**Single Quotes:**

**`'C:\WATIR\gopal\**'.gsub("\\", "\/")`**

**use single quote to prevent escaping '\'**

**Double quotes:**

If you want to use only doublequote:

**`puts "C:\\WATIR\\gopal\\**".gsub("\\", "\/")`**

This gives o/p:

**`C:/WATIR/gopal/**`**

**Is this because the '\ ' is interpreted as a special character in the double quote string but in the single quoted string the characters are preserved as is**

**Difference between single and double quotes:**

Ruby only interprets escape sequences in double quoted strings.

In a single quoted string, only \ (backslash backslash) and \' (backslash quote) are taken as special characters.

You should use double quoted strings only when you need more interpretation.

Otherwise, single quotes provide a performance boost.

Comment: No, My original string is that, If I had to change that to \\ then I can change that to /. Anyhow I find the answer now. `'C:\WATIR\gopal\**'.gsub("\\", "/")`, It works fine. Changing "" into '' works.

Comment: please check the answer now.